# Intellij Sql Script Commit Interval

Tags: intellij-idea

When using intellij's `Run SQL Script...` command, the scripts I run will be committed at periodic intervals, even if auto-commit is disabled.

- The scripts are only insert statements, and don't explicitly commit or change the auto-commit level.
- The interval may be size-based as shorter insert statements don't commit as frequently as longer ones.
- I'm aware of the impact a large number of uncomitted rows in a session can have and why this is might be the preferred behavior.

**How do I change/disable this feature ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no possibility to do that now. The transaction mode needs to be supported in Run Configuration for databases. The ticket is:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-11301